# WebStorm typings inferring

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings, package.json

I'm building a library using TypeScript. I created declaration files and added the '*typings*' option to my package.json (I also tried using '*types*').
Now my problem is when I try to install the package, WebStorm won't infer the typings (in contrary to the way it works with Angular2 for example).

It seems like I'm missing something with my package.json / typings, so:

index.d.ts:

```
declare module 'my-library' {
  export * from "my-library/index";
}

declare module 'my-library/index' {
  export {
    LibraryLogic
  }
  from "my-library/LibraryLogic";
}

declare module 'my-library/LibraryLogic' {
  export class LibraryLogic {
    constructor(someNumber: number);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
import { LibraryLogic } from 'my-library';

let a = new LibraryLogic(3);
```

**Note**: Everything compiles just fine, it's just that it would be easier for programmers to use my library if WebStorm would auto-complete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works fine for me using WebStorm 2016.3.3.

My setup:

1. in my project `package.json` I have added `"my-library"` as a dependency
2. in `node_modules/my-library/package.json` I have: `"types": "./index.d.ts"`

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the fast response. I was wondering whether WebStorm auto-completes you about the parameter you should pass to (new LibraryLogic(number)). I mean does it tell you to insert a number there that was name x in the class?

Comment: it shows `somenumber:number` when you choose `new LibraryLogic` from completion, or when you hit `Ctrl+P` within parentheses

Comment: Not sure what was the difference between mine and yours but I followed your instructions 1 by 1, restrated WebStorm and Vwalla. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Everything compiles just fine, it's just that it would be easier for programmers to use my library if WebStorm would auto-complete them.

- If your library works fine with TSC
- And `declare module 'my-library/index'` etc is only needed for WebStorm

Then please raise an issue with WebStorm.

## Why

Webstorm uses its own closed source code intelligence on top of TypeScript and stackoverflow can't help you here.

It should work fine with Raw TypeScript (aka VSCode / alm.tools etc).

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is smart enough to find your typings folder, but WebStorm is not. You need to add your @types folder to compilerOptions in tsconfig.json.

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./typings"] // <-- Add your typings path here
  },
```

typeRoots helps typescript find your custom typings folders. Finally, double check your IDE is using your tsconfig.json file.

Official Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html